# How good would a Divine Metal Industry be?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

**This question contains massive spoilers. If you do not wish to have your game experience spoiled, do not scroll down!**

According to the [Dwarf Fortress Wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Angel#Angel_types):

> "Even if you kill all the angels inside a vault, they will eventually respawn (no confirmation yet about how long it takes--a cleared vault has been witnessed having its population back in under a month) which makes vaults pretty good high-level item grinding grounds."

You can embark at Vaults if you have DFhack (there are other ways, but this is the fastest).

> If I avoid getting slaughtered by the Vault-Clowns, I could set up a way to kill them with cave-spider-webbed traps or catapults every time they re-spawn.

How good of an industry would this make?

I am willing to take the risk of **[!!FUN!!](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Losing)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divine metal is better than steel for everything but blunt weapons.  Divine blunt weapons are about equal to steel.

Divine metal is a little worse than adamantine for cutting weapons, better than adamantine for blunt weapons, and about equal for armor.  Divine metal also survives dragonfire, though a suit of it won't protect the dwarf inside.

Logistically, divine metal has a huge advantage over adamantine.  The trick where you can get more metal than you put in by melting certain items works fine on divine metal but is much more difficult with adamantine, because divine metal comes in bars while adamantine comes in wafers.

Whether that's worth it is up to you.

Comment: Was infinite metal via stack-splitting + smelting for adamantine recently changed?  It definitely [worked fine in previous patches](https://www.reddit.com/r/dwarffortress/comments/fql316/infinite_adamantine_using_elf_labor/).

Comment: It does work with Adamantine Bolts. But I don't want to use that kind of exploit.